# How to run a function instead of text in this wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is a simple code which shows the Adsense or any ad code after second paragraph on single post page. But I want to know how to modify it so that it can run a dynamic function.

```
//Insert ads after second paragraph of single post content.

add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );

function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

    $ad_code = '<div>Ads code goes here</div>';

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

In fact I want to replace

```
$ad_code = '<div>Ads code goes here</div>';
```

with

```
 $ad_code = '<?php if(function_exists('echo_ald_crp')) echo_ald_crp(); ?>';
```

Is there any way to do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't assign PHP to a `string var` and expect it to execute. You could create a function with the code in it, have it return something, and then set the variable equal to the function call. Like this:

```
function output_function() {
    //do something here
    return $thing_you_want_to_return;
}

function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

    $ad_code = output_function();

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

That way, when the variable is assigned, it'll run your function and return what you want to be echoed out with `prefix_insert_after_paragraph()`.